# How to solve _.some using _.every?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Working on a programming challenge to re-implement the functionality of underscore.js in standard javascript.  Specifically I am working on implementing the `_.some` function.  (http://underscorejs.org/#some)
The part I'm struggling with is it's asking me to find a way to solve it using `_.every` internally.  (http://underscorejs.org/#every)

I have already finished the `_.every` function earlier and it works as it should.

Here is logically what I am wanting to do in sketched code:

```
_.some = function(collection, truthStatementFunction) { 
  return !(_every(collection, !truthStatementFunction)) 
}
```

Or in english, flip the truth statement to test where the condition is false... and if the `_.every` test then returns true...  then we know that _.some of the original truth statement is false (so flip the return of `_.every` to get the correct return for `_some`).  Likewise if `_.every` returns false then flip that to get the correct return of true for `_.some`.

Obviously the problem with this sketch is the `!truthStatementFunction` part.  How do I get inside that iterator to change the internals of the function to flip it?  Doesn't seem that the internals of the function are accessible...

Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely, and there is a better way to solve this using `_.every`?

Comment: You got the right idea. However, you need to [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) the `!` operator and the function; it's something like `function(x){return !truthStatementFunction(x)}` instead of just `!truthStatementFunction`.

Comment: To answer your question...  It's a learning exercise so the point is to learn, one way or another (although I know solving it 100% on my own would be the most effective way to learn, getting stuck too long and wasting time that I could be spending learning other equally useful things does me no good).  I'd prefer to get a hint here rather than an outright answer, but I wasn't sure if that would run afoul of stack overflow's seemingly stringent rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass `_every` a function that returns an inversion of the result from `truthStatementFunction`:

```
_.some = function(collection, truthStatementFunction) { 
    return !(_every(collection, function(v) {
        return !truthStatementFunction(v);
    }));
}
```

To answer the second part of your question:

> and is there a better way to solve this using _.every?

There is definitely a better way to solve this than using `_.every`. Just iterate over the collection, and return true as soon as you find any element that matches. Much more efficient in cases where `_.some` is going to return true, since you don't really care how many elements in the collection satisfy the predicate, as long as there is at least one.

```
_.some = function(c, pred) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (pred(c[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  With all the scopes I was looking at I forgot that I could explicitly define the function I was passing into _.every (_.every is itself using _.reduce internally to satisfy the challenge, so the scopes are starting to get a little confusing!)

By the way at the end I was asking if there was a better way to solve USING _.every, not NOT using _every...  I agree a for loop would be much simpler than all this!

Comment: @ggg The reason I was suggesting a for loop was not simplicity, but rather efficiency. Using the `_.every` approach is *a lot* slower (on average) than the simple iteration.