# why does simply returning the opposite of the _.every function not work in implementing the _.some function?

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js

Here is my _.every function:

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    if(iterator === undefined){
      iterator=_.identity
    }
    return _.reduce(collection, function (isTrue, element){
      if(iterator(element)) {
        return isTrue;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }, true);
};
```

I'm wondering why, when implementing _.some, I can't just write it like this to have the correct functionality:

```
    _.some = function(collection, iterator) {
      return !_.every(collection, iterator)
    }
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Negation using the `!` exclamation mark is possible, however you are missing a semicolon at the end of the `return` statement.

Comment: So `!every(xs, p)` means that if all `xs` satisfy `p` return `false` otherwise return `true`. This is not the same as saying that at least one `x` must satisfy `p`. See duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157348/how-to-solve-some-using-every

Comment: Thanks! The duplicate question helped out allot. Yeah i realized my question needed to include the inverse of the some iterator as well. I was just wondering why we need to call iterator in a function instead of just passing through correctly as an argument to some.